# expand log on Octave

Tags: octave

I am trying to expand log expression with octave like that:

```
expand(log(x^2))
```

to get `2 * log(x)`

but that doesn't work
That works with matlab when making:

```
expand(log(x^2),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true)
```

but octave doesn't recognise it.

Any idea how to make it with octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that x is a positive variable first.

```
pkg load symbolic
x = sym('x', 'positive' );
expand( log( x ^ 2 ) )      % ans = (sym) 2⋅log(x)
```